# Запятая вариативна?

Tags: запятые, ссп

Помогите с рассуждениями. Такое предложение:

**Они его отвезли в больницу и там его начали лечить.**

Если лечить будут те же, кто и отвезли, то запятая перед «и» не нужна, а если лечить будут другие люди, то нужна? Правильно?

Comment: Нужно знать контекст. Иначе вопрос ваш становится загадкой.

Comment: Только это предложение )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно верно, к вашим рассуждениям нечего и добавить!

Да, в первом случае *отвезли* и *начали лечить* однородные члены, а *они* объединяющее слово, а во втором два простых предложения формируют одно сложносочинённое.

Если люди одни и те же, то я бы убрал второе местоимение:

*Они отвезли его в больницу и там начали лечить.*

Хотя по наличию или отсутствию запятой можно однозначно судить о смысле, но так будет точно ясно, что автор не ошибся и не проявил неграмотности, не поставив запятой, а имел в виду именно такой смысл.

Comment: Можно добавить, что во втором случае второе простое предложение — односоставное, неопределённо-личное, что не должно смущать: запятую в этом случае всё равно никто не отменяет.

Comment: Совершенно верно, Егор. ;)

Comment: Допустим, не читаем, а слышим этот текст. Запятая — как нам поможет?

Comment: @shampar Пауза подскажет.

Comment: @shampar: хотел сказать, что не поможет, что интонация может быть совершенно одинаковая, но теперь подумал, что всё-таки действительно, как говорит oleedd, может быть небольшая пауза в случае ССП, если выразительно читают. Но не уверен, что должна быть явная разница...

Comment: **Логическое ударение**, пауза — разница должна быть заметной, если правильно читать.

Answer (score 1):

Да, всё верно. Только, если люди одинаковые, запятая тоже возможна (при наличии паузы), если считать, что пропущено местоимение:
*Они его отвезли в больницу, и там [они] его начали лечить.*

При этом очень важна структура предложения, чтоб звучало по-русски. Оригинальная структура подходит больше для разных действующих лиц. В другом случае звучит не очень. Для одинаковых желательно переставить первое местоимение:
*Они отвезли **его** в больницу и там его начали лечить.*
А лучше и второе:
*Они отвезли **его** в больницу и там начали **его** лечить.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой А вот и нет. Основа у меня: *Только запятая тоже возможна.* А без запятой нестыковки со смыслом.

Comment: Странно, рассматривал такой вариант, но уж больно чудно так... Прости! Тогда поправь, пожалуйста, обратно.

Comment: *Уж больно чудно так...* — есть такое, но по-другому не получается, если менять местами.

Comment: В любом случае "только" можно к придаточному чисто отнести.

Comment: Нет, тогда получается, что запятая тоже возможна только в случае, когда люди одинаковые. Как-то бредово.

Comment: Не понял логики.

Comment: Переставляем: *Запятая тоже возможна, только если люди одинаковые.* В чём смысл? К чему здесь "только"? Оно не в тему.

Comment: "Только" тогда в значении не "исключительно", а **но!** В том же, что и ты имел в виду.

Comment: Ладно, тогда получается самостоятельное примечание, но запятая тогда плохо подходит — из-за двусмысленности. Лучше тире или начать новое предложение. *Но, если люди одинаковые, запятая тоже возможна* — в исходном варианте НО не может войти в придаточное.

Answer (score 1):

**Они его отвезли в больницу и там его начали лечить.**

Запятая вариативна? У меня на этот счет есть сомнения.

Вот детский рассказ. *Мы всей семьей гуляли в лесу и нашли под кустом маленького зайчика с больной лапкой. **Мы его принесли к себе домой  и начали там лечить.** Вскоре зайчонок поправился.*

Запятая вариативна?

Вроде бы нет. Никто не сомневается, что запятой здесь нет, так как это однородные сказуемые.

А это заданное предложение: ***Они его отвезли в больницу и там его начали лечить.***

Вроде бы всё похоже, но здесь, оказывается, два ответа!

1. Но неужели это предложение можно считать сложным? В редких случаях – да, но это вузовская программа или художественная литература. Причем желательна значительная семантическая расчлененность сказуемых, их разная грамматическая форма и уверенность в наличии двух разных ситуаций. **Другими словами, не школьная это тема.**
2. Содержание заданного предложения можно записать так: ***Они отвезли его в больницу, где ему оказали необходимую медицинскую помощь.*** Просто и понятно. Но здесь стояла другая задача – переделать текст в учебный и создать видимость вариантов. Будто бы постановка запятой  зависит от одинаковых или разных производителей действия.

Скорее всего, они разные, это ясно и без контекста, да и само предложение сложным не выглядит, хотя  смотрится немного странно из-за попыток менять порядок слов и имитировать эту самую расчлененность.

3. Но не одинаковые или разные производители  действия здесь важны – здесь важна **однозначность грамматики**, а вот ее отсутствие – это всегда **стилистическая** ошибка. У нас же здесь – намеренная стилистическая ошибка!

И вот мы начинаем думать, кто привез и кто лечил, но это не предмет для грамматики в принципе. В неопределенно-личных предложениях часто вообще непринципиально, кто является производителем, и мы чисто **условно** мыслим его одинаковым.

4. Ох уж эти составители учебных программ! Они любят придумывать предложения, хотя они не писатели, и любят сокращать классику, хотя вряд ли имеют на это право. Как говорится, о времена, о люди!

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ

1. Попробую очень коротко сформулировать свое мнение, которое, как я думаю,  **понятно не всем** (иначе мне придется считать свой ответ «совершенно неправильным», в отличие от уже принятого и совершенно правильного).

(1) *Они его отвезли в больницу и там его начали лечить* (заданное предложение).

(2) *Мы принесли зайчика домой и начали его там лечить* (похожий пример).

2. В обоих случаях это грамматика простого предложения с однородными сказуемыми, где предполагается **один и тот же  производитель действия.**

С точки зрения смысла такая грамматика подходит для предложения (2), где производитель действия для нас неважен.

Но такая грамматика **совершенно не подходит для предложения** (1), где производители действия, скорее всего, **разные**.

3. Таким образом,  **грамматическая форма противоречит семантике,** создает дискомфорт (с почти  ироническим или детективным подтекстом) и поэтому является **стилистической ошибкой**.

Выход очень простой: надо заменить грамматическую форму любой другой: *Они отвезли его в больницу, где ему оказали медицинскую помощь.*

4. **Примечание**.  В школьной практике проблема различения производителей действия актуальна для **односоставных неопределенно-личных** предложений, например:

Стали искать черкесов во всех углах и, разумеется, ничего не нашли (Л.); Подсудимых тоже куда-то выводили и только что ввели назад (Л. Т.); Из церкви возвращались домой, ели пироги и снова ложились спать до вечера (М. Г.); http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Но и там один и тот же производитель  действия мыслится  **весьма условно** (к примеру, конвойные могут меняться, но для нас это неважно). Грамматически мы приравниваем такие предложения к однородным членам и запятую не ставим.